# How to get automake to set libdir to /usr/lib64 on dual-arch Linux platforms

Tags: centos6, autoconf, automake

I'm maintaining an autotools-configured project, and I've noticed in a plain autotool setup:

```
libtoolize --verbose --copy --force
aclocal --verbose -I m4 -Wall
autoheader -Wall --verbose
autoconf -Wall --verbose
automake --add-missing --force-missing --copy --warnings=override -Wall
./configure --prefix=/usr
make 
make install
Installing libexample.so in /usr/lib
```

that the make install resulting from my build (on x86_64 arch, linux) puts
generated libraries in `$prefix/lib`.

I was expecting the library(s) to have an `$LIBDIR` set to `$prefix/lib64`.

- Is there something I should do differently, or
- is there a 'secret' m4 macro to automatically determine this, or
- is the the expected behavior?

Comment: With more recent versions of autotools, it tries to determine whether to install to `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64` by examining `configure`'s  `--host` flag.  You didn't say what version of autotools you are using.

Comment: By any chance, you don’t mean the —target flag?

Comment: Autoconf 2.63 is the version in question. Automake 1.11

Comment: I meant `--host` @EgbertS:  you are performing a [native](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Configure-Terms.html) build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this on CentOS 6.9.  Unfortunately, the [official Upstream Vendor response to having a reasonable `config.site` installed](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=772997) is CLOSED WONTFIX.  I also was able to reproduce this on CentOS 7.4.

`config.site` is the usual way this works on most distros.  They do provide suggestions for a workaround:  Basically backport whatever Fedora's `config.site` does.

FWIW, the distro I'm currently using where this works does this by exporting `CONFIG_SITE` in `/etc/profile.d/site.sh`:

```
CONFIG_SITE="/usr/share/site/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
export CONFIG_SITE
```

and the relevant part of `/usr/share/site/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` does something like:

```
 if test "$libdir" = '${exec_prefix}/lib' ; then 
       ac_config_site_64bit_host=NONE

       case "$host" in
       "" )
       ... sort through 32-bit cross-compilation ...

       *x86_64* | ... other 64-bit architectures ...)
               ac_config_site_64bit_host=YES
               ;;
       esac

       if test "x$ac_config_site_64bit_host" = xYES; then
               libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib64'
       fi
  fi
```

something similar could work for you.

Alternatively, you could just specify `--libdir` as the RPM packages apparently do.